# Iterating over a "class" attribute in HTML in python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML string from a website. Below is part of what is present in it.

```
<p class="news-body">
<a href="/ci/content/player/45568.html" target="new">Paul Harris,</a> the South African spinner, is to retire at the end of the season, bringing to an end a 14-year first-class career.
</p>
<p class="news-body">
 Harris played 37 Tests for South Africa with his slow-left arm but nearly turned his back on international cricket after a stint as a Kolpak with Warwickshire in 2006. The retirement of Nicky Boje prompted Harris' eventual call-up and he went on to take 103 wickets at 37.87.
</p>
<p class="news-body">
His last Test was in Cape Town against India in January 2011 after which he was dropped for legspinner Imran Tahir. As recently as the start of this season he indicated his intention to compete for a Test place once again.
</p>  </div>
   <!-- body area ends here  -->
```

I would like to extract all of the above text that is present inside ALL of `<p class="news-body">`.

I have used Beautiful Soup.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = #the HTML code you've written above
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html)
print parsed_html.body.find('p', attrs={'class':'news-body'}).text
```

Unfortunately the above only returns the first line, which is:

```
Paul Harris,the South African spinner, is to retire at the end of the season, bringing to an end a 14-year first-class career.
```

I would like it to return all the text.

Answer (score 1):

`find` finds only the first element. You want `findAll`, which will return a list of elements.

You can join their text together like this:

```
text = '\n'.join(element.text for element in soup.findAll('p', ...))
```

Also, I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'